# Meaning of structure operations

Tags: c++

Assume i have

```
struct node{
  int val;
  node* left;
};
```

Now, I have a `priority_queue<node> sth;`
What does the following do:

```
node temp = sth.top();// does it perform copy
sth.pop();
temp.left = sth.top(); // is this allowed?
```

How do I pop an element from the queue and store it in `temp.left`?

Comment: You have been here over a year and have asked 118 questions and still don't know how to format code samples in questions?

Comment: It must be the first time I ever see a `std::priority_queue` complaining about its own formatting. :)

Comment: @sth: Sounds like laziness. I'm going to stay out of this one. (lol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181321/simple-c-implementation-throwing-error)

Comment: @sth: I am sorry. I thought I indented it but i think mistyped ...my sincere apologies

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node temp = sth.top();// does it perform copy
```

Yes, this makes a copy of the top element and stores it in `temp`.  `temp.left` points to the same place as top node's left pointer.  Note that `top()` actually returns a reference but this line asks for a copy.  `node &temp = sth.top();` would declare a reference to the top element.

```
sth.pop();
```

Removes the top node from the queue.  **You may have just broken your data structure here.**  Any pointers to that node object (e.g., left pointers of other nodes in the queue) are now invalid.

```
temp.left = sth.top(); // is this allowed?
```

No, this won't compile.  `temp.left` is a pointer and `top()` returns a reference to an object.  At a minimum, you need to get the address of that object: `temp.left = &sth.top();`